# How to create a List from another class in main method?

Tags: java, list, class, arraylist

I created this class to become an object in the controller class

```
public class Student 
{
    private String nisn;
    private String grade;
    
    public String getNisn() {
        return nisn;
    }
    public void setNisn(String nisn) {
        this.nisn = nisn;
    }
    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }
    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
}
```

and I wanted to make an ArrayList that contains String nisn and grade in controller and client(main method) class

I've tried this code but it shows an error. So how to create the correct code to create ArrayList that contains variables in Student class? Thanks

```
public class StudentController
{
    Student students;
    public void readData()
    {
        students = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows "an error"? What error? A `Student` isn't an array of students--you've defined `students` as a single `Student`. You can't then make it be an array list of strings. You need a `List<Student>`, no?

Comment: Remember, it's always helpful to add the error that you're seeing into your question, as well.

Answer (score 4):

Let's go through with what is wrong currently.

First, this line: `Student students;` creates a single instance of `Student`. Do you mean `Student[] students` or `List<Student> students`?

Second, if you do change it to a List, you are trying to set it as `ArrayList<String>` at `students = new ArrayList<String>();` This does not work because `Student` and `String` are different Types.

To get the nisn of each student, you first fill the list with students, and then iterate over the students, getting the values wanted:

```
students = new ArrayList<Student>();
//Create and add all the students
List<String> nisns = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Student student : students){
    nisns.add(student.nisn);
}
```

You can do the same thing to get each grade:

```
students = new ArrayList<Student>();
//Create and add all the students
List<String> grades = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Student student : students){
    grades.add(student.grade);
}
```

If you need to keep track of whose grades and nisns are whose, then use a `HashMap<Student, String>`, where the `Student` is the student and `String` is the nisn or grade, depending on whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Dave is right.  You'll need to define students as a List, like this:

```
List<Student> students;

public void readData() {
    students = new ArrayList<Student>();
}
```